# SharePoint 2016 Issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, configuration

I am in the process of setting up a fresh SharePoint Server for the very first time. I have completed the installation, but am encountering a few issues that don't seem to want to be solved.

1. Accounts used by application pools or service identities are in the local machine Administrators group. - I was sure to use a domain admin account, which I removed form the machine's local admin group, yet this error persists.
2. The Unattended Service Account Application ID is not specified or has an invalid value. Error: "The rule for the Unattended Service Account Application ID failed. The ID does not exist. Visio Graphics Service"  - I followed the prescriptions suggested by [this](http://www.spjeff.com/2010/08/17/the-unattended-service-account-application-id-is-not-specified-or-has-an-invalid-value/) tutorial, and the error persists.
3. I am trying to migrate the Admin_Content_GUID database to an equivalent 'non-GUID' database, yet it tells me they have different schema and the migration is not possible. I am attempting this using the SharePoint Shell Commands and have done the 'psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade' multiple times.

Please give some insight into what I might be missing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information on which service is calling out for the unattended service account application ID.

Comment: The rule for the Unattended Service Account Application ID failed. The ID does not exist. Visio Graphics Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use Domain Administrator accounts for SharePoint. It's not needed. Also, this error must be resolved on a per-service basis. Please edit your question with the services the error is calling out as not all services can be resolved; typically once resolving the services that can be changed, I disable the health rule.

You cannot migrate the Admin content database. You need to instead rebuild your farm using PowerShell so you can specify an admin database name.

Here is a sample script for building a new farm via the SharePoint Management Shell.

```
#2016 Farm
$configDb = "SP2016_Config"
$adminDb = "SP2016_Admin"
$dbServer = "SPSQL"
$farmPassphrase = "Password1"
$farmAdmin = "DOMAIN\s-farmadmin"
$role = "Custom"

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0
New-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName $configDb -DatabaseServer $dbServer -AdministrationContentDatabaseName $adminDb `
    -Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString $farmPassphrase -AsPlainText -Force) `
    -FarmCredentials (Get-Credential -Message "Farm Admin" -UserName $farmAdmin) -LocalServerRole $role
Initialize-SPResourceSecurity
Install-SPService 
Install-SPFeature -AllExistingFeatures
New-SPCentralAdministration -Port 8080 -WindowsAuthProvider NTLM
Install-SPHelpCollection -All
Install-SPApplicationContent
```